# ElementUI: el-table__fixed height change

Tags: css, vuejs2, element-ui

I have a weird problem with [ElementUI's](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table) `el-table` element. My table renders just fine, but when I navigate to another route and then come back to the view with my table, the height of the `el-table__fixed`-element has decreased by 17px.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is there a bug in ElementUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

While inspecting my app with the Vue DevTools, I saw that my `ElTableBody` was rendered twice. After some searching, I found this [Bug Report](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/12177). Turns out, the problem was setting `fixed` to `true` on my `ElTableColumn` elements. After removing the `fixed` prop, everything renders just fine - even when returning to my view.